# Can I pass the current x display user as a parameter in a udev rule?

Tags: linux, udev, systemd

I've got a udev rule set up which restarts a systemd service, passing in a user parameter for the service to run as.

The trouble is udev runs as root so it always passes in root as the paramter. I would like to somehow get the user who owns DISPLAY 0 and pass that in as the parameter.

Bit of background:
I'm trying to achieve automounting of usb drives and optical media with udevil, under any user and without the aid of a desktop environment.

Is this possible?

This is my current rule:

```
# check for blockdevices, /dev/sd*, /dev/sr* and /dev/mmc*
SUBSYSTEM!="block", KERNEL!="sd*|sr*|mmc*", GOTO="exit"

# check for special partitions we dont want mount
IMPORT{builtin}="blkid"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="EFI|BOOT|Recovery", GOTO="exit"

# /dev/sd* and /dev/mmc* ith partitions/disk and filesystems only and /dev/sr* disks only
KERNEL=="sd*|mmc*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition|disk", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem", GOTO="harddisk"
KERNEL=="sr*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", GOTO="optical"
GOTO="exit"

# mount or umount for hdds
LABEL="harddisk"
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl restart udevil-mount@/dev/%k.service"
ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl stop udevil-mount@/dev/%k.service"
GOTO="exit"

# mount or umount for opticals
LABEL="optical"
ACTION=="add|change", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl restart udevil-mount@/dev/%k.service"
GOTO="exit"

# Exit
LABEL="exit"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no good method for tat.

In Unix there *is* no "current" user nor current display, nor any guarantee that display :0 would exist and belong to an actual user at any moment. Even Microsoft has learned years ago that letting services reach "into" a user session is a bad idea (resulting in "session 0 isolation").

Run the `devmon` daemon (or `udiskie` as an alternative, or perhaps thunar-volman), from within the user's graphical session (e.g. start it via /etc/xdg/autostart or /etc/X11/xinitrc.d). Let it monitor udev events that way.